# How to clear DataGrid rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagrid

I've a dataGridView and I fill the dataGridView at run time
When I tried to update grid it is give me error:

"This list is not cleared."

```
DataGrid_A.Rows.Clear()
GetDataGrid()
```

How can I solve this problem?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Databound datagridview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the desired result

```
   do
   {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGrid_A.Rows)
    {
      try
      {
        DataGrid_A.Rows.Remove(row);
      }
       catch (Exception) { }
     }   
   } while (DataGrid_A.Rows.Count > 1);
```